# Translate SQL query to LINQ (subqueries)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Hi have a site where users can vote on images.
The votes are stored in table Votes where I store the Id of the submission (FK_id)

The tables are:

**Table Submissions**
Id (uniqueidentifier)
Name (varchar(50))
Image (varchar(50))

**Table Votes**
Id (int)
Fk_id (foreign key to Submissions.Id)

I'm new to linq so I don't know how to translate this:

```
SELECT *, 
    isnull((SELECT count(*) 
    FROM Votes
    WHERE Fk_id = S.Id      
    GROUP BY Fk_id),0) as Votes 
FROM Submissions S
```

I wanted something like this:

```
List<Model> = (from p in ????
               select new Model
               {
                   Name = p.Name,
                   Image = p.Image,
                   Votes = p.Votes               
               }).ToList();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than translate your Sql (which I think is overly complicated), don't you just want to do something like :

```
List<Model> = (from p in Submissions 
              select new Model
              {
                 Name = p.Name,
                 Image = p.Image,
                 Votes = p.Votes.Count() 
              }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a fairly straight port to me, other than the order of `select` and `from` being reversed.

```
Submissions.Select(sub => new
{
  //...other fields
  Votes = Votes.Where(vote => vote.Fk_id == sub.Id)
               .GroupBy(vote => vote.Fk_id)
               .Select(group => group.Count()),
}
```

Now, looking at the query you could probably just do the group by on Votes directly, rather than as an inner query, and it should be quite a bit more efficient, but that's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

This would be translation of your `SQL` code, which also takes into account `isnull` ensuring that there is model for each submission:

```
List<Model> list = (from s in Submissions
        select new Model
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            Name = s.Name,
            Image = s.Image,
            Votes = (from v in Votes
                     where v.Fk_id == s.Id
                     group v by v.Fk_id into g
                     select g.Count()).FirstOrDefault()
        }).ToList();
```

If you are using `Entity Framework` you should ensure that your data model is generated correctly.
In this case your `Submission` entity would already contain `Votes` as property. Then everything is easy as:

```
List<Model> list = (from s in context.Submissions
                    select new Model
                    {
                        Id = s.Id,
                        Name = s.Name,
                        Image = s.Image,
                        Votes = s.Votes.Count()
                    }).ToList();
```